# Display menu bar items of IE using Python

Tags: python, internet-explorer-8

Is it possible in Python to list all the items of the File menu (as shown on the picture)  of Internet Explorer version 8 ?

These are what I want to list:

[image]

Comment: You could use the [ctypes library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) to access the Windows API and create such auch functionality by yourself. [This function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647833(v=vs.85).aspx) is a good way to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to know the target window title. Then you can simulate a mouse button click or use the <kbd>Alt / Menu</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> shortcut to open the menu.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from ctypes import windll

def main():
    find_window = windll.user32.FindWindowW
    send_message = windll.user32.SendMessageW

    window_name = u""
    window_handle = find_window(0, window_name)

    if window_handle > 0:
        show_menu(handle)
    else:
        print("Window handle not found")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If you want the first solution (mouse clicks), then add:

```
WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100
WM_KEYUP = 0x0101

def point_to_long(x, y):
    return (y * 0x10000) + x

def show_menu(handle):
    target_pos = point_to_long(30, 40)
    send_message(window_handle, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 0, target_pos)
    send_message(window_handle, WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, target_pos)
```

Otherwise (key pressing), use:

```
VK_MENU = 0x12
VK_F = 0x46

def show_menu(handle):
    for key in (VK_MENU, VK_F):
        send_message(window_handle, WM_KEYDOWN, key, 0)
        send_message(window_handle, WM_KEYUP, key, 0)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Just one last question, if I may: can i follow the same schema you gave me  if i want to calculate the number of toolbars that appear on Internet Explorer browser ? Or is is an other complete process for which i must ask a new question instead ?

Comment: You're welcome. I don't think so, a toolbar may be located in different positions depending on the user preferences. Maybe you can try searching in the registry for *installed* toolbars.